# jsTree - How to load data using xml having english as well as german language?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jstree

I am using XML for loading data using ajax call in jstree. My data contain both English and German content. I can see English content perfectly but it showing **"?"** in place of German characters. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are having an encoding issue. Did you set it to UTF-8 ?

Comment: Please show how you are loading the XML into your jsTree. I believe you change something like `contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8"`.

Comment: i am loading data as:                                                                          "xml_data" : {
          
 "ajax" : {
 "url" : function(node){
  var level="";
  if(node == -1){
       return ctx+"/tree/loadTree.html";
   
  },
      "type" : "get", 
      "success" : function(ops) {
   return ops;}
  }
 },